# Views from the module won't display (CodeIgniter HMVC)

Tags: codeigniter-3

I'm actually working in an admin panel, and I want to manage all my sliders inside it,
so I created all the functions etc...
In the view file where I want to call the view from the module by running

```
<?php 
echo Modules::run('sliders/_slider_display);
?>
```

But, The the sliders won't display, I will show you how I did it.

```
function _slider_display() {

 $current_url = current_url();
 $query_ads = $this->get_where_custom('target_url', $current_url);
 $num_rows_ads = $query_ads->num_rows();
 if($num_rows_ads>0){
  $this->load->module('slides');
  foreach($query_ads->result() as $row)
  {
    $parent_id= $row->id;
  }

  $data['query_slides']= $this->slides->get_where_custom('parent_id', $parent_id);
$this->load->view('sliders', $data);
 }
}
```

as I mentioned, I tried to call the view in the homepage, but did not worked, I don't know what is the problem.

Thank you !

Comment: did you get any error there?

Comment: I got no errors, that's why it's kinda weird.

Comment: are you getting any slider or just blank data means $query_ads return data or not

Comment: it's just blank